# errors compiling Qt with Intel C++ compiler for Win32, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, intel

I have opened MSVS 2010 command prompt, from where I've run ips-vars.cmd from Intel Parallel Studio (which sets up environment for ICC), from where I called:

```
configure -ltcg -debug-and-release  -graphicssystem opengl -mp -platform win32-icc -no-s60
```

And got this:

```
Creating qmake...

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    icl -Yuqmake_pch.h -FIqmake_pch.h -Fpqmake_pch.pch -c -Fo./  -W3 -nologo -O2    -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators\unix -Igenerators\win32 -Igenerators\mac -
    Igenerators\symbian  -IH:\Alex\Alex\Work\Qt\4.7.3\include -IH:\Alex\Alex\Work\Qt\4.7.3\include\QtCore  -IH:\Alex\Alex\Work\Qt\4.7.3\include -IH:\Alex\Alex\Work\
    Qt\4.7.3\include\QtCore  -IH:\Alex\Alex\Work\Qt\4.7.3\src\corelib\global  -IH:\Alex\Alex\Work\Qt\4.7.3\src\corelib\xml  -IH:\Alex\Alex\Work\Qt\4.7.3\mkspecs\win
    32-icc   -IH:\Alex\Alex\Work\Qt\4.7.3\tools\shared  -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_LITE_COMPONENT -DQT_NODLL -DQT_NO_STL  -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -DUNICO
    DE -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_NO_THREAD  -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED  -DQLIBRARYINFO_EP
    OCROOT /Zc:forScope -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION H:\Alex\Alex\Work\Qt\4.7.3\src\corelib\plugin\qsystemlibrary.cpp
    qsystemlibrary.cpp
    Catastrophic error: cannot open precompiled header file "qmake_pch.pchi"

    compilation aborted for H:\Alex\Alex\Work\Qt\4.7.3\src\corelib\plugin\qsystemlibrary.cpp (code 4)
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Intel\Parallel Studio 2011\Composer\bin\ia32\icl.EXE"' : return code '0x4'
    Stop.
```

Any ideas what's wrong?
Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `-Yu` means "use precompiled header".

Seems like you haven't first created a precompiled file (`-Yc`). And that one should probably not end in `.h`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Do you happen to know where are compiler's commandline arguments specified in Qt? -Yc is not present in qmake.conf

Comment: @Violet - Sorry, I don't know QT, just the compilers. But you do have a `.pch` file in your command. Could that be the one you should use?

Comment: I don't understand precompiled headers (googling it right now), the only thing I've noticed so far is there are no *.pch files there.

Comment: @Violet - It is a way of compiling huge headers once, and save the result. Then you can reuse that for other compiles and possibly save some compile time. See here [MSDN Precompiled Header Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szfdksca.aspx). Works the same for the Intel compiler in MSVC mode.